# Form page not redirecting to desired page in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

So I made a form page that should direct its input values into a registration page from laravel, but controller is not redirecting to the register page after the form is filled and sent,

```html
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Providers\RouteServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;


class InviteController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */
    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Renderable
     */
    public function index()
    {
        return view('invite');
    }  //

    
    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo =  RouteServiceProvider::REGISTER;

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [


            'username' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users']


        ]);
    }


}
```

Here is the form method in the invites.blade.php

```html
                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf
```

and the route in web.php

```html
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/invite', 'InviteController@index')->name('invite');
```

and this is the route service provider I entered.

```html
  /**
     * The path to the "home" route for your application.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public const HOME = '/home';
    public const REGISTER = '/register';
```

Comment: use this command `php artisan route:list` and see `register` is which under?

Comment: POST     | register               |                  | 
 App\Http\Controllers\Auth\RegisterController@register

Comment: SO how do you use this in `InviteController` ??

Comment: Can't use it in {{ route('invite') }} returns a "The POST method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: GET, HEAD.
"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use like this

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('invite') }}">
```

And your `routes/web.php` use like this

```
Route::post('/your_url_name', 'InviteController@your_function_name')->name('invite');
```

Comment: I get this error when I put the Route on Route::post "The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST."

Comment: It never shows this error. Please check your form submit action `post`

Comment: this happens when i change Route::get('/invite', 'InviteController@Index')->name('invite');
to
Route::post('/invite', 'InviteController@Index')->name('invite');

Comment: Fixed by having it as both get and post :


`Route::get('/invite', 'InviteController@Index')->name('invite'); `
`Route::post('/invite', 'InviteController@Index')->name('invite');`

Comment: But really only post method is enough. But problem solve is main

Comment: It gives me the above error if Route::get is not mentioned.

Comment: OK. I understant.